# Tar without directory structure and exclude folders

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, tar

I am trying to create a tar file [`site.tar.gz`] to exclude certain folders and without the parent directory structure:

I am able to exclude folders, but when I extract, I see path from the root

```bsh
tar -czvf site.tar.gz /var/www/html/site --exclude="/var/www/html/site/images"
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182036/101265

Answer (score 0):

Do not execute the tar where you want the tar file to be created, but from the directory you want to tar:

```
 cd /var/www/html/site ; tar -czvf /path/to/site.tar.gz . --exclude="/var/www/html/site/images"
```